# Performance overhead with "-g" (debug) flag of GCC?

Tags: performance, gcc, benchmarking

What is known about performance overhead with the "-g" flag (debug) of GCC? For small examples, I see no difference.

Comment: What does the documentation for the `-g` flags say?

Comment: Zero difference, it just adds metadata (debug info) to other sections of the executable.  That metadata works less well in optimized code (`-O3 -g`), e.g. you sometimes just get "optimized out" for local var values, especially if a loop was auto-vectorized.